# Many things do it. What is this?

Tags: riddle, science

> Sometimes wind does this, at other times water does this.
>
> Sometimes insects do this, at other times birds do this.
>
> Sometimes humans also do this.
>
> This thing keeps life moving.
>
> This is best delivery system that is running from years and years ago.

What is 'this'?

Comment: "Sometimes Human's also do this .." so the human does it or is it inside a human?

Comment: Are the upper case letters in Wind and Human a hint or just typo's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its:

> **Pollination**

Because

> And Water, wind, insects , birds and humans are medium of pollination (transferring pollen grains)

Comment: well human does it.. could be. but "This is best delivery system" ?

Answer (score 1):

Is the Answer:

> Sound (or) Music.

Because:

> The Wind, Water, Insects, Birds, Human may makes sound and music.

And:

> Music can keeps life moving.

Final:

> Music is the best delivery system for many years.

Comment: nice ,but I am thinking something else.

Comment: Got it... Thinking Something else..